# How to integrate ANTLR with CMake?

Tags: cmake, antlr

I'm trying to make CMake generate source files with ANTLR without any success.

Here command I'm using to generate these files:

```
$ antlr grammar/MyGrammar.g -fo src/parser
```

My executable target is defined in `PROJECT/src/CMakeLists.txt`, instead of `PROJECT/CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying you want to execute this command from within `PROJECT/src/CMakeLists.txt`, then the following should work:

```
execute_process(COMMAND antlr grammar/MyGrammar.g -fo src/parser
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
```

#### Edit

Going by your comment, it looks like you want to invoke this every time you build your executable.

To tie the antlr invocation with your executable, you can use [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command)

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND antlr grammar/MyGrammar.g -fo src/parser
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
```

This will only execute the antlr call if the MyExe target is out of date.  If MyGrammar.g is changed, but MyExe doesn't need rebuilt, antlr doesn't run.

If you have multiple targets which depend on antlr being run, or you want to be able to invoke the antlr command any time, you could instead use [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target).  This adds the antlr command as a new psuedo-target.  If you just build this target, all it does is invoke antlr.  For each target which depends on it, use [`add_dependencies`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_dependencies):

```
add_custom_target(Antlr 
                  COMMAND antlr grammar/MyGrammar.g -fo src/parser
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..
                  SOURCES ../grammar/MyGrammar.g)
add_dependencies(MyExe Antlr)
add_dependencies(MyOtherExe Antlr)
```

As before, antlr will only be invoked if one of the dependent targets needs rebuilt, or if you explicitly build the new custom target "Antlr".  (You don't *need* the `SOURCES` argument in the `add_custom_target` call, but this convenience feature adds MyGrammar.g to the target's files visible in IDEs like MSVC)

Comment: It process is executed only once. I need it to be executed everytime grammar changes.

Comment: I can't make much progress with this. The source generated by antlr must be compiled as well. However, at the time cmake generates the makefiles, the source files may not even exist. So any GLOB that would cover those source files will not find them. Hence, those sources will not appear in the generated makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit off topic but maybe it will be usefull for you.
[Here](https://tora.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tora/trunk/tora/src/libantlr3c-3.3/CMakeLists.txt) you'll find CMake build file for the ANTLR C runtimme library.

Generated sources are same as any other sources generated from metadata.
You can use QT's UIC complier macro as an example:

```
    MACRO (QT4_WRAP_UI outfiles )
    QT4_EXTRACT_OPTIONS(ui_files ui_options ${ARGN})
    FOREACH (it ${ui_files})
      GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(outfile ${it} NAME_WE)
      GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(infile ${it} ABSOLUTE)
      SET(outfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ui_${outfile}.h)
         ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${outfile}
         COMMAND ${QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE}
         ARGS ${ui_options} -o ${outfile} ${infile}
         MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${infile} VERBATIM)
      SET(${outfiles} ${${outfiles}} ${outfile})
    ENDFOREACH (it)
    ENDMACRO (QT4_WRAP_UI)
```

Comment: I can build library, but I want to execute custom commands in my build :)